# Raspberry PI zero v1.3 end of life

Tags: pi-zero

I want to know What is the expected end of life of the  raspbery pi zero v1.3 ?

i need more than 100 pcs for my project and and now i do not see stock on thepihut for such qty.

Comment: Why not ask the manufacturer?  raspberrypi.org

Comment: You cannot get the Zero in quantities from resellers. RPF/RPT will do it for a higher price per unit. You need to contact them directly

Comment: According to this (you don't have to watch the video, just search the article): https://www.techrepublic.com/article/raspberry-pi-3-b-co-creator-eben-upton-reveals-all-about-the-new-board/ *"**No** Pi board will hit End of Life until 2022"*.